# Clifford Lie algebras

Tags: clifford-algebras, lie-algebras, reference-request

I'm studying the "Clifford Lie Algebra" (see [Lachieze-Rey - Spin and Clifford algebras, an introduction](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2481) page 30).
It's basically a way to look at Clifford algebras and their properties in a Lie algebraic
setting (which I find appealing). I'm looking for a reference that looks at this in more
detail; one that discusses the Lie subalgebras even better.

Comment: Clifford algebras provide a natural way to construct spin groups... The Lie algebra aspects are just the usual, natural things. I don't really know what you are wanting... Could you elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

A little bit of what you want can be found in Chapter 5 of Gracia-Bondia, Varilly, and Figueroa's book *Elements of Noncommutative Geometry.*  They don't say much about subalgebras, I think, but they do prove (Lemma 5.7, page 182) the result that bivectors in the Clifford algebra $Cl(V)$ are closed under taking commutators, and that the adjoint action of bivectors on vectors in $V$ induces an isomorphism of the Lie algebra of bivectors with $\mathfrak{so}(V)$.  That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to track this down. Finding $so(n)$ in $cl(n)$ is, as expected, easy to do; here $cl(n)$ is the Clifford lie algebra; it has dimension $2^n-1$ (I think this can also be extended to be $2^n$). $so(n+1)$ also shows up in $cl(n)$ if I did my calculations correctly.

Comment: I do not understand the statement about the dimension.  The Clifford algebra $Cl(V)$ is an associative algebra of dimension $2^n$ when $\mathrm{dim}V=n$.  Then it acquires a Lie algebra structure where the Lie bracket is the (scaled) commutator.  This does not change the dimension.
Also, upon examining these notes a little more closely, I would say that if you want to learn about Clifford algebras and spinors from a mathematical viewpoint, you would be better off consulting another source.  These notes are coming more from a physics perspective (which can be useful if you're a physicist)...

Comment: but the presentation here is kind of *ad hoc.*  For instance the Clifford algebra of $V$ is defined not as a quotient of the tensor algebra of $V$ but as a new multiplication on the exterior algebra $\Lambda(V)$.  So if you're going to be rigorous about things, you need to *check* that this new product is associative.  On the other hand you get that for free if you define it as a quotient.
In addition to the book I recommended above, another good (and classic) source is Chevalley's monograph *The algebraic theory of spinors and Clifford algebras.*  A different viewpoint is given in...

Comment: *Clifford algebras and spinor norms over a commutative ring,* by Hyman Bass.  But that one is probably much more general than what you're looking for.

Comment: I agree with you on the dimension, it should be $2^n$; there is an
element in the lie algebra that commutes with everything; my guess is that the authors did not want to include it. Clifford algebras are a
large field and my guess is that angle is just not very popular. One motivation for me is the ability to look at the adjoint rep of $cl(n)$ as a rep of $so(n)$; for example $cl(4)$ $\to 1 \oplus 4 \oplus 6 \oplus 4 \oplus 1$ as an $so(4)$ rep...

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anyone else who calls this the "Clifford Lie Algebra".  It is just one of the basic applications of Clifford algebras.   Given the Clifford algebra of a quadratic form, the quadratic elements of the Clifford algebra give you the Lie algebra of the orthogonal group of that quadratic form.

There are many places to read about this, one of them would be Chapter 1.6 of "Spin Geometry" by Lawson and Michelson.  I've written up some notes for a graduate course that include this, see here:

http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/LieGroups-2012/cliffalgsandspingroups.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is actually the other elements (non-quadratic) that make things more interesting. Altogether these give
a $2^n$ dimensional lie algebra which can stand on its own as an abstract lie algebra that includes $so(n)$ as a lie subalgebra.
The multivectors correspond to invariant subspaces of this subalgebra (adjoint action). Also $so(n+1)$ and I believe $so(n+2)$ also occur as lie subalgebras...all this motivated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Complex Clifford algebras are isomorphic to complex matrix algebras with a Bott periodicity 2. For $n=0,1,\cdots$,
$$\mathrm{cl}(2n)\cong\mathbb{C}(2^n), \mathrm{cl}(2n+1)\cong\mathbb{C}(2^n)\oplus\mathbb{C}(2^n),$$
where $\mathbb{C}(N)$ denotes the algebra of $N\times N$ complex matrices. Taking these matrices as Lie group generators, they will generate general linear transformations over the complex field via the exponential map:
$$M\in \mathbb{C}(N)\mapsto\exp(M)\in \mathrm{GL}(N,\mathbb{C}).$$
Therefore, one can conclude that the complex Clifford Lie algebra should be isomorphic to complex general linear algebras as
$$\mathrm{cl}(2n)\cong \mathfrak{gl}(2^n,\mathbb{C}),\mathrm{cl}(2n+1)\cong \mathfrak{gl}(2^n,\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathfrak{gl}(2^n,\mathbb{C}).$$
Real Clifford algebra will have a richer structure with Bott periodicity 8, but the general idea will be similar.